# Excel VLookUP on drop down list

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have two sheets in excel, Submission and Validation.  On my Validation Sheet I have my two sources of information. Column G holds my community names, the thing in my list. Column H holds my NumberCode, the thing I want to auto populate.

Example Validation:

```
G       H
Venice  26423
Scarborough 24741
```

On my Submission sheet I have a data validation drop down list. whose information is:

[image]

I am trying to lookup the codes so that when my dropdown list has Venice, the cell next to it should auto-populate 26423. My latest iteration of the Vlookup code is:

```
=VLOOKUP('Validation Page'!G1:G1067,'Validation Page'!H1:H1067,,FALSE)
```

I have tried putting it into tables, putting it into name reference, ect but nothing seems to want to populate. I either get #N/A or another error. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try puting this in the cell tahat you need populate with the number code

```
=VLOOKUP('Submission Page'!G1,'Validation Page'!G1:H1067,2,FALSE)
```

change 'Submission Page'!G1 for the correct cell where the drop down list is

Comment: Yes this was the problem thank you. I was trying to refer to itself instead of the cell I needed pull the data from. Thanks!