# If x=a1, then y=b1 if x=a2, then y=b2

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a drop down list that correlates to a list of values in column A. when one is selected, i want the cell below to display the value in the same row but in column B

- A1   B1
- A2   B2
- A3   B3
- A4   B4
- A5   B5
- A6   B6
- A7   B7
- A8   B8

If i select A1, B1 is displayed, A5, B5 is displayed, etc.

Comment: Vlookup should do the trick

Comment: this may help [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42987984/excel-vlookup-on-drop-down-list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42987984/excel-vlookup-on-drop-down-list)

Comment: Have a look at vlookup here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/57560079/4961700